# Reading and Exporting OSM Road Data as Network of Road Segments [Adjacency Matrices]

Tags: qgis, python, openstreetmap, network

I wish to extract from an OSM file a road network, and export it as an array (adjacency matrix) where the nodes are the road intersections and the edges represent the road segments.

I don't want to just visualise it, but also export the resulting adjacency matrix as a file with a network data structure in at least one of the following formats: numpy file (.npy), pajek file (.net), gephi file (.gexf), csv file (.csv). Alternatively, a list of nodes and edges with geometric info would do.

I seek a solution using either Python or QGIS.

I was hoping for something [like this Matlab package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35819-openstreetmap-functions), especially the 3rd item in the description. Unfortunately, I don't have Matlab installed on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know an exact solution, but will try to present you general ideas:

What you are looking for is adjacence matrix for an routing graph that is generated out of OSM geodata. While there is a huge interest in the [routing topic](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) at the community, there are just very few approaches to export the routing graph, as user usually want a full featured routing solution.

- [eWorld](http://eworld.sourceforge.net/) is a frontend for the [SUMO](http://sumo-sim.org/) engine that enables this simulator to make use of OSM. You can get network files etc.
- [osm2pgrouting](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgrouting) fills a PostGIS DB according to the requirements of the [pgrouting](http://pgrouting.org/) module
- QGIS [road graph plugin](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_road_graph.html) can also be used on OSM for example with the OSM import plugin or with preprocessed shapefiles
- [osm4routing](https://github.com/Tristramg/osm4routing) might fit your export requirements, but I never heard of it before so I guess it's not in wide use...

A last idea would be to play with the [trafficmining framework](http://code.google.com/p/trafficmining/) that seems to be very modular, so I guess you can get access to the processed data (but it's in JAVA)

All in all it depends on your use case.

Comment: I will look into SUMO. What I have done so far is implement `Vector` > `Analysis Tools` > `Line Intersections` and export the attribute table as a shapefile with both latitude and longitude information. From there, I use Python (packages `pyshp` and `networks`) to extract and build the network.

Answer (score 1):

http://osm-traffic.com/ allows direct download of graph data from OpenStreetMap in json format.

Disclaimer: I work with the company who developed it, it might become a pay service.

Answer (score 0):

A systematic method has been developed for this according to NIH ["A protocol to convert spatial polyline data to network formats and applications to world urban road networks"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4915275/)

Comment: OP wants (pure?) Python or QGIS, and this discusses some ArcGIS tool the authors made for extracting routable networks from OSM. So only tangentially related to the question.