# How can I transform OSM road data to a graph network in 2018?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, network, graph

I see a lot of questions in this topic, but most answers are at least 4-5 years old. I wonder if there is a more current solution that would allow me to gain a graph network from the OSM highways data.

Simplicity is key.

Previous discussions:

[How to Build a graph from a map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104452/how-to-build-a-graph-from-a-map)

[Read and Export OSM Road Data as a Network of Road Segments [Adjacency Matrices]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83256/read-and-export-osm-road-data-as-a-network-of-road-segments-adjacency-matrices)

Comment: Add links to old answers which look most promising to you.

Comment: Please note that it is not helpful for the discoverability of good answers to duplicate questions every couple of years. You can [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw attention to the original question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).